# Как создать аудио плеер в Android Studio со всеми Controls?

Tags: android, плеер

Надо создать аудио плеер для андроида.
Если есть пример ваших решений, скидывайте ссылки на ресурсы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для работы с аудио файлами вам необходим класс `MediaPlayer` он и занимается проигрыванием.

Ваш вопрос очень обширен, и написание своего плеера довольно не тривиальная задача, т.к. кроме обычных операций включить/пауза/стоп, вам нужно будет еще реализовать механизм слушания аудио потока системы, например при входящем звонке надо остановить проигрывание и при его окончание возобновить проигрывание.

В качестве источников знаний могу посоветовать две статьи :

1 - [Хорошая на хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/339416/)

2 - [Чуть похуже, но более обширная. На английском](https://www.sitepoint.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-building-an-android-audio-player-app/)

Comment: Вот именно, надо всё учитывать, а я в данный момент хочу создать приложение "аудио плеер" для андроида. Круто было бы если кто нибудь показал бы свой код. И на этом примере я бы сделал свой аудио плеер. Надеюсь найдётся такие люди, которые покажут свой код для. А Вам спасибо. Прочитаю статьи которые прикрепили.

Comment: во второй статье есть четкий пример от А до Я как написать рабочий плеер. И так же там ссылка на гитхаб с исходниками, в первой так же есть код, но там чисто на тему аудио.

Comment: Большое спасибо и правда всё чётка там описано.